# Voom transformation of RNA seq raw counts data

Tags: r, limma

I have RNA seq data of raw gene counts that I want to transform for linear modelling. I am trying to voom transform, to do a weighted analysis.

Data frame: prac_count_10

```
gene         S1     S2    S3   S4    S5 
ENG0000456   0      1     10   145   24
ENG0000458   7      2     9    0     0
ENG0000657   76     12    56   10    2 
ENG0000689   0      0     0    3     5
```

Code:

```
prac_prac_10 <- voom(prac_count_10[,2:5], design=NULL, lib.size=NULL, 
  normalize.method = "none", span = 0.5
```

However this doesn't give an output with the gene sample names and logCPM values. Would like an output with gene id's and logCPM values for linear modelling.

Also tried:

`````````````
cpm <- cpm(prac_count_10)
lcpm <- cpm(prac_count_10, log=TRUE)


````````````
`````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `DElist()` function before you transform, and also make rownames first.

```
counts <- prac_count_10[,-1]

rownames(counts) <- prac_count_10[,1]

DGE1 <- DGEList(counts)
```

And then continue with your voom...

Comment: Thank you. what package is DElist in?

Comment: That would be edgeR.

Comment: If I do:   ``````prac_count <- data.frame(prac_count, row.names=1), counts<- prac_count[,1], rownames(counts) <- prac_count[,1], DGE1 <-DGEList(counts) `````` If doesn't work... have I missed a step? Thank you so much

Comment: That's not the code I gave in my answer, is it?

Comment: Don't mention it! Good luck with it.